# Extract data from the XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have string in C# which has the following

```
  responseString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n<lab:labs xmlns:lab=\"http://njjhjhjh/ri/lab\">\n    <lab uri=\"https://dsdsdsds.org/api/v2/labs/1\">\n        <name>Administrative Lab</name>\n    </lab>\n</lab:labs>\n"
```

I want the uri value `https://dsdsdsds.org/api/v2/labs/1` to be extracted and stored in a string

```
           string xmlString =responseString.Replace("lab:labs>", "labs>");
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(xmlString);
            XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("labs//lab");
            if (nodes != null && nodes.Count > 0)
            {
                XmlNode node = nodes[0];
                if (node.Attributes["uri"] != null)
                {
                    string return_uri = node.Attributes["uri"].Value.ToString();

                }
            }
```

But the above code is throws error like  `{"The 'lab:labs' start tag on line 2 position 2 does not match the end tag of 'labs'. Line 6, position 3."}`. Is there a simple way of getting that uri value

Comment: That's because you're mangling your XML.  Don't do that; instead, use namespaces properly.

Comment: Also, use `XDocument`; it's much nicer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(responseString);
var result = doc.Descendants().First(d => d.Name=="lab").Attribute("uri").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick for you

```
var urival = xdoc.Descendants("lab").Attributes("uri");
```